# Fourier transform trick in solving Legendre's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

Differential equations can often be solved by the method of Fourier transform. I have a particular equation in mind that appears very often in physical applications which is the Legendre differential equation: $$(1-x^2)y^{\prime\prime}-2xy^{\prime}+l(l+1)y=0.$$ I know that this can be solved by the method of series solution. But does the Fourier transform trick work here? If not why?

Comment: Modulo constants and justification of differentiating under the integral sign, the Fourier transform of $x^ny^{(m)}(x)$ is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n y^{(m)} e^{-ikx}dx= \frac{d^n}{dk^n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^{(m)}e^{ikx}dx=\frac{d^n}{dk^n}\left( k^m\widehat{y}(k)\right)$$
So in this case, applying the Fourier transform gives an equation of the form
$$\alpha(k)\widehat{y}''(k)+\beta(k)\widehat{y}'(k)+\gamma(k)\widehat{y}(k)=0$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are polynomials ($\alpha$ of degree $2$). This is the same type of ODE we started with, so the situation hasn't simplified.